# The record should be created only once for an object

Tags: validation, business-logic

For a product only one once an incentive can be created according to this business process how can i restrict it form creating more than one record.

Comment: Can you elaborate (by update to your question) on the datamodel and relation between your objects ?

Comment: @Sdry Thank u so much for ur reply, A custom object is created with the master object as Opportunity, let's name it as incentive, in that there are lot of fields, Consider for a single opportunity there should be only one incentive, This is the case... :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Birthus outlined but that will not work if using the API instead of the UI. You need some sort of validation using an insert trigger. It would essentially check the value of the rollup summary field and if the value is currently greater than 0, reject the insert.

```
trigger IncentiveTrigger on Incentive (before insert) {
  for (Incentive i : Trigger.new) {
    if (i.Opportunity__c.rollup_field__c > 0) {
        // throw your error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely agree this is the approach...but the story is a little more complicated because this won't prevent double records being inserted simultaneously. 

You'd need a separate check to make sure that none of the incentive records in Trigger.new have the same parent Opportunity. Also, Updates are tricky if you need to support re-parenting.

Comment: I am using a professional Edition can't use Triggers :(

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the solution will be to create 1-to-1 relationship.

First of all create a master detail relationship and than create a Roll-up field to count child objects. then create validation that will check if Roll-up field >1 
Thanks to that you will receive the error message if it has more than one child record.

Comment: Perfect i too did the same before... but what it happens is the record gets included and then the Roll-up field gets incremented after that the 2 records that are created already cannot be edited and it's validating correctly when 3rd record is being created.

Comment: About old data....
How about create non-displayed Boolean field (just for existing data ) that will allow them skip validation rule?
 You can also trigger Validation rule only for objects created after some date.
Or instead Validation rule use addError() in the trigger. In trigger you can easly use it only for new data.
But in my oppinion best way will be dataFix